# Improve CSV push to MySQL with virtual files in python

Tags: python, mysql, windows, performance, virtualfilesystem

I am trying to find a way to improve the speed while pushing data to a MySQL database using pandas in python.

After my performance tests I arrived to the same conclusion that  other people did: the best way to push data to a MySQL database is to use the native query 'LOAD DATA INFILE..." instead of the to_sql pandas method (even with improvements like [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15276) or [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953)).

My problem is that when I want to push my data, it is in memory. So in order to use the native MySQL query, I need to dump it first into a file on the disk and then use the 'LOAD DATA...' query.

So here my question, is there a way to 'simulate' a file written on the disk so i can avoid dumping my big files (200MB+) on it ?

It might happen that dumping a big file can take some minutes, so I would not want to lose too much time there...

Comment: you mean something like tmpfs ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: yeah something like this but for windows

Comment: Then you may want to remove the python and panda tags (they are totally irrelevant) and add the "windows" one.

Answer (score 0):

This approach *may* be a viable alternative without touching disk (for the load file):

Write code to create multi-row `INSERT` statements and execute them.  Suggest 1000 rows at a time, with autocommit=ON.